# angular ng-bootstrap popover not working on div

Tags: angular

i am using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) for popover. it's not working when a mouse hovers on div.

```
<div class="card" placement="right" ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on right" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien ipsum. Morbi pulvinar est sed metus vehicula consequat. Proin et mi mauris. Nam faucibus arcu ac eros cursus semper. Aliquam erat volutpat. 

</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cEExyhMhmjutJKNJnd4y?p=preview). I replaced `placement="right"` with `placement="top"` because the popover is barely visible at the right of the div.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you and sorry for delayed reply. I will try.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it's working fine with bootstrap4. previously I try with bootstrap 3.